# Trigger opacity transition on mouse in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to trigger a opacity transition. If an element is hovered by the cursor, the cursor shall fade out, change its background-image and then fade in again. I wanted to achieve that by adding and removing a css class. It's not working, what is wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aa68zyzu/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="cursor">
   </div>
   <div id="grey">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: lightgrey;
padding: 60px;    
cursor: none;
}

#grey {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: grey;

}

.cursor {
position: fixed;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s; /* Safari */
transition: opacity .3s;
}

.red {
background: red;
opacity: 1;
}

.green {
background: green;
opacity: 1;
}
```

JS

```
  $('.wrapper').on('mousemove', function(e){
        $('.cursor').css('left', e.clientX-10).css('top', e.clientY -10);
       if ($.contains($('.wrapper')[0], e.target)){

        $('.cursor').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
    }else{
        $('.cursor').removeClass('red').addClass('green');
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/aa68zyzu/5/)**

Ok, here you go. You need to keep track of 2 things here which you already achieved partially and also wait for `fadeOut` to complete and add a callback for adding and removing respective `class`

> - Whether cursor has entered element
> - Whether cursor has left element

Below is how you could actually do it.

```
var entered=false;//global variables to show the position of cursor
var left=false;
$('.wrapper').on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.cursor').css('left', e.clientX-10).css('top', e.clientY -10);
    if ($.contains($('.wrapper')[0], e.target)){
        if(!entered)
        {
            //just to do it once and not on every mousemove you need to check here whether 
            //it has already entered and moving inside the element
            entered=true;
            left=false;//to check the vice versa operation
            $('.cursor').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                //callback function after fadeOut completes
                $(this).removeClass('green').addClass('red');
            }).fadeIn('fast');
        }
    }else{
        if(!left)
        {
            left=true;
            entered=false;
            //same goes here too
            $('.cursor').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
            }).fadeIn('fast');
        }
    }  
});
```

Comment: @vuvu.. Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @CodeiSir.. My answer is specific to what OP has asked and meeting his requirement. If he would have asked for `background` then definitely I wud have differently.. :)

Comment: on Ray's post he said: "[...] in reality it is an background image" - crazy guy^^

Answer (score 0):

you have to change background color , not opacity ( opacity is always 1 )

CSS

```
.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s; /* Safari */
    transition: background-color .3s ;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: no, I just made it easier for hier, in reality it is an background image

Comment: wow, you cant just ask one question and then downvote the answer because you in reality your question is wrong

Comment: yes, 2 different background images, I just used backgroundcolor in the example code, but i also want it to fade out

Answer (score 0):

So you said your question is wrong, it is "no, I just made it easier for hier, in reality it is an background image" - so you transition between two background-images.

Here is how you do it:

- You can not do it with CSS transition in ONE element/div
- You will have to make two divs wich one background each
- Increase the zIndex of the div you want to fade out in by one
- Fade out div, while the new div stays at `opacity: 1`